# python social auth with django custom user model

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-socialauth, python-social-auth, django-custom-user

I'm using `python-social-auth` (not django-social-auth because it's depreciated) for authentication in Django REST backend applciation with `Custom User Model` described below.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, UserManager

class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Gender():
        MALE = 0
        FEMALE = 1
        UNKNOWN = 2
        CHOICES = [(MALE, 'Male'), (FEMALE, 'Female'), (UNKNOWN, 'Unknown')]

    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and '
                    '@/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(r'^[\w.@+-]+$', _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
        ])
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=Gender.CHOICES, default=Gender.UNKNOWN)
    birthday = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
    objects = UserManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ ensure instance has usable password when created """
        if not self.pk and self.has_usable_password() is False:
            self.set_password(self.password)

        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Notice that I don't implement a custom `UserManager`. Social auth pipline is also straightforward.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
      'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
      'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
  )

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)
```

However, when I try to authenticate with Facebook, it gives an error as below

`TypeError at /api-token/login/facebook/
'is_superuser' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

The problem is, probably, `python-social-auth` try to use django's own User instead of custom User Model that I defined.
In `django-social-auth` there is a setting's parameter like `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL` but I couldn't find any way to do it in `python-social-auth`

How can I make it possible to use my custom user model in python-social-auth?

Comment: You can set the custom user in `python-social-auth` in the same way with `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL` (some docs at http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/settings.html?highlight=social_auth_user_model#user-model).

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a Custom UserManager as well described below. I removed `is_superuser=is_superuser` field while creating new user.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, username, email, password,
                     is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, False, False,
                                 **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, True, True,
                                 **extra_fields)
```